# mgo collection.Find(nil).All(&users) not working

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm having the next issue..
I can't get all records from my mongo database (running in a docker containner), here is my really simple code:

```
type User struct {
    Email string `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Pass  string `json:"pass" bson:"pass"`
}

session := dbConnect()
collection := session.DB("my_db").C("users")
var users []User
err := collection.Find(nil).All(&users)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal("Mongo collection find fail: ", err)
}
fmt.Println("Results >> ", err)
```

The thing is "err" returns `<nil>`. Something weird is that inserting documents on the database actually works. Thank you!

Comment: What does `fmt.Println("Users >> ", users)` print?

Comment: It prints "`<nil>`"

Comment: well <nil> is the zero value for an empty slice and there is no errors, so it seems that your collection 'users' is empty

Comment: but in the mongo shell, if I run `use my_db` and then `db.users.find()`, it returns several json documents..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with your code, but the last line `fmt.Println("Results >> ", err)`, shouldn't it be `fmt.Println("Results >> ", users)` ?

Also you can check if collection is not empty and fields are correct by using interface

```
session := dbConnect()
    collection := session.DB("my_db").C("users")
    var v []interface{}
    err := collection.Find(nil).All(&v)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Mongo collection find fail: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Results >> ", v)
```

Comment: You're right, thank you. I'm just getting used to pointers and references in Go.